# Why javascript 'window.location.hash' does not work in WKWebview in ios11?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, wkwebview, ios11, xcode9

it can work in ios10 or before , but it can not work  in ios11?

```
- (void)jumpToHash:(WKWebView *)wkWebView {
NSString * jsJumpToHash =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"function jumpToHash(){window.location.hash ='#%@hash';};",self.hashLocation];

[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:jsJumpToHash completionHandler:^(id Result, NSError * error) {}];

NSString *jsFun = @"jumpToHash()";

[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:jsFun completionHandler:^(id Result, NSError * error) {}];

self.hashLocation = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS11, window.location.hash doesn't have support to scroll to location.

Please use following code for scroll web page to selected location

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var hashElement=document.getElementById('%@');if(hashElement) {hashElement.scrollIntoView();}", href]];
```

Comment: This works, but just a comment: hashElement does not have to have the "hash" sign itself to work. E.g.: If your element is "#header" you have to pass "header" as href in this code.